# Unexpected output after using snprintf

Tags: c, printf, overlapping

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    struct test
    {
        char buff[255];
        char sour2[30];
    };
    struct test p;
    char sour1[255] = "try to do code";
    strcpy(p.sour2, "Create experimental data.  Just take the regular simulation data and add some gaussian noise to it.");
    int n = snprintf(p.buff, 255, "%s", sour1);
    printf("%s\n %s \n",p.buff, sour1);
}
```

Expected output:

```
try to do code
try to do code
```

What I got instead:

```
ake the regular simulation data and add some gaussian noise to it.
ake the regular simulation data and add some gaussian noise to it.
```

Why do I get this output? How can I apply the overlapping concept here because `sour1`, `p.sour2` are in two different memory locations?

Comment: `strcpy(p.sour2,...` is a buffer overflow. That's undefined behavior. Anything may happen.

Comment: In other words: It's not `snprintf` that give you problems, it's `strcpy`

Answer (score 2):

Your code invokes undefined behavior, the destination buffer of `strcpy` is too small to store the source string.

From the `strcpy` [linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html):

> ```
> char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
> ```
>
> *The strings may not overlap, **and the destination string `dest` must be
> large enough to receive the copy**.  Beware of buffer overruns!  (See
> BUGS.)*

BUGS section:

> ***If the destination string of a `strcpy()` is not large enough, then
> anything might happen.**  Overflowing fixed-length string buffers is a
> favorite cracker technique for taking complete control of the
> machine.*

The C standard establishes the concept of undefined behavior as follows:

> ### C11 N1570 Draft §3.4.3
>
> ---
>
> 1. ***undefined behavior***
>
>    *Behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.*
> 2. ***NOTE***
>
>    *Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).*
> 3. ***EXAMPLE***
>
>    *An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.*

This is what happens in your program, the result is completely arbitary, there is no explanation for it as per the definition of undefined behavior, only an analysis of the generated assembly of your particular build can shed some light on what is happening.

As you can see in [this online compilation](https://godbolt.org/z/Khca8e), three different compilers deal with this problem in a different way and also differently compared to your local compiler, and yet differently from my local build which produces the expected output before crashing.